# what is the error in this ssh connection?

Tags: svn, ssh

I am trying to commit to svn repository through hudson .

```
 export SVN_SSH="ssh -v "
 svn commit --username user --password pass -m "message" file.sql
```

by debug the error part seems to be

```
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/app/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/app/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/atgapp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Received disconnect from 192.xxx.xxx.xx: 2: Too many authentication failures for atgapp
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I am new to ssh and not able to find the error here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is looking for key(RSA) needed for SSh  connection with Git Hub, I believe you can give a try using RSA key that can be downloaded from Git Hub Repository.

Thanks
Abhay Johri